# Generate Unique Order ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to generate one unique order ID. I already have some code but I can't verify if the order already exist.

```
<?php
$exists = 1;   
while($exists > 0) {

    $store = "TLP"; //This one is just to appear before the random number Those are like the initials of the shop
    $orderid = substr(str_shuffle('0123456789'), 0, 3);
    $exists = $this->count_rows('tblorders', "WHERE oder_orderid=" . $store . $orderid);

    $value8 = $store . $orderid;
    echo $value8;

}?>
```

But im not getting anything from `echo $value8;`.

I just need one way to get the result `$value8` verified and if there is one equal generate another one, and if there is no one equal exit the loop and keep the `$value8`

```
$store = "TLP";
$orderid = substr(str_shuffle('0123456789'), 0, 3);
$value8 = $store . $orderid;
```

the result of the code above would be something like `TLP123` but I need one way to verify if `TLP123` is already in my column and if it is in the column generate another one.

EDIT: Also tested with this one but got nothing too.

```
      function check_number(){

    $store = "TLP";
    $orderid = substr(str_shuffle('0123456789'), 0, 3);
    $value8 = $store . $orderid;
    $exists = $this->count_rows('tblorders', "WHERE oder_orderid='" . $store . $orderid."'");



    if ($exists >0){
        $results = check_number();
    }
     else{
            $results = $value8;
        return $results;
     }
echo $value8;

}
```

Comment: How does $this->count_rows work? Your echo statement should at least echo out TLP if nothing else. Do you have error reporting and display errors turned on?

Comment: @MrCarrot yes my error reports are on, but I don't have any error and that code is not doing anything I think, at least my echo is empty, I don't know how can I verify it, thats why im asking it.

Comment: If you change it so that $exists = 0; in the loop, what happens? Also after 999 order numbers this will never succeed? And will become very slow even before that happens.

Comment: @MrCarrot nothing, I got nothing one my page if I change it to 0

Comment: So do you want an SQL query that tells if TLC123 is in the database for example?

Comment: @Jek Yes is that what I want, and if that order id is already in database he should generate another.

Comment: Aside from the antipattern of building the query with string concatenation, which is not a good practice even with untainted data, a problem you have here is a potential race condition.  Two parallel processes will eventually generate the same ID, both will find that it doesn't exist, and proceed to stomp all over each other, not "if" it happens, but "when."  You need to understand transactions and locking database reads before you can actually implement this correctly.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - To counter this OP you want to use a possible minimum of 7 digits `(0000000->9999999)` to 12 digits `(0000000000->9999999999)`, small is 7 digits, companies with multiple inputs per client `(possibly 100's)` is the 12 digit or more! Also, to counter the string concatenation issue, just use a `prepared statement` - `binding parameters to a query` - look up `prepared / binding queries`! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, was at school and I didn't wanna get caught, but if you're still having the problem, you can use `PDO` in this way:

```
$statement = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'what_id_to_search_for'";
$query     = $pdo->query($statement, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); # FETCH_ASSOC just returns an assosiative array.
if ($query->rowCount())
{
  # The row exists! Do again! (re-call function, etc...)
} else {
  # The row doesn't exist! Woo! We can insert!
}
```

If you're using MySQLi, etc... please let me know I'll delete my answer cause I don't like that connection language, and if that doesn't make sense I can rewrite it to make it simpler for you,

Also, I don't see why you don't just use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` type and then just set a type like `TLP` for example. :-)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$exists = $this->count_rows('tblorders', "WHERE oder_orderid=" . $store . $orderid);
```

to:

```
$exists = $this->count_rows('tblorders', "WHERE oder_orderid='" . $store . $orderid."'");
```

Comment: The code that I posted there is giving me this error `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\xampp\htdocs\orders\test.php on line 21`

Comment: you will need to post the $this->count_rows function